# Styling all copies of elements inside shadow-root's at once on third party sites/browser internal pages

Tags: google-chrome, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools, shadow-dom

### General issue

How can one restyle all copies of an element whose implementation is hidden inside a shadow root? Currently, (Chrome 71.0.3578.98) if I go into the chrome dev tools, turn on shadow roots in the settings, and start making changes to things inside shadow roots, it only affects the one element I've selected, not identical elements within other shadow element "hosts" on the same page.

How can I (as a user of a page; not the developer of it) restyle all elements inside shadow roots at once?

### Specific example

The Chrome bookmark manager has been designed to hide urls of bookmarks by default and will only show one url at a time when a bookmark is in focus.

I would  like to restyle it so I can see all the urls for my bookmarks at the same time.

If I open dev tools, expand a `<bookmarks-item>` and it's `#shadow-root`, select the `<div id="website-url" ...>` element, and in the `Styles` tab uncheck the `display:none;` rule for `#website-url` it will only affect that one element I selected because the style rule is hosted within that element and only affects that element.

How can I apply a style that will affect all `#website-url` elements within  `<bookmarks-item>` in the Chrome bookmarks manager?

(NB: it doesn't have to be persistent, or automatic. Just something I can type/paste in the chrome dev tools console will do.)

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS is written out inside each shadowRoot then you can't. Unless you override their component and make your own and use your code to do the override.

If the CSS inside the shadowRoot is just a `<link href="component.css" rel="stylesheet">` tag or uses `@import 'component.css';` then you can change the content of `component.css` that is loaded by the component and it will affect them all.

Comment: Is it possible to override components on someone else's page? Could you give an example of how to do that?